# Initializing a 2-D Array in java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, 2d

Little confused why this isn't working could use a little help, I want to set all the values to false:

```
boolean[][] seatArray = new boolean[4][4];

for(int x = 0; x < seatArray.length; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < seatArray.length; y++){
        seatArray[x][y] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: (The default values will be false already, by the way...)

Comment: Although the answer by Elizion below makes a good point, I can't spot a problem in your code. What exatly does not behave as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that you are iterating over the correct array element in your inside `for` loop to set every value to be `false`. Try this:

```
boolean[][] seatArray = new boolean[4][4];

    for(int x = 0; x < seatArray.length; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < seatArray[x].length; y++){
            seatArray[x][y] = false;
        }
    }
```

***EDIT***: Your code should still work, but for convention you should still probably do this.

Comment: This answer is correct but in the question the array size is 4x4 so `seatArray[x].length` is the same as `seatArray.length`.

Comment: @DimaMaligin That's interesting, you are correct. I just assumed that was the error as my presented code works for me!

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to explicitly set any value.

The primitive `boolean` defaults to `false`.

Hence:

```
boolean[][] seatArray = new boolean[4][4];
System.out.println(seatArray[0][1]);
```

**Output**

```
false
```

Answer (score 0):

BY defaultif u initialize a 2D boolean array it will contain value as false
 Lets say you have a two dimensional array as

```
boolean[][] seatArray=new boolean[4][4];//all the value will be false by default
so it is a 4*4 matrix

boolean[0] represents the the 1st row i.e Lets say it contains value like {true,true,true,true} if you need the value in individual cell you need to iterate 2 for each loop like

    for (boolean[] rowData: seatArray){
                for(int cellData: rowData)
                {
System.out.printn("the indiviual data is" +cellData);
                 cellData=Boolean.false;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work but here is another solution for filling a 2D array:

```
    boolean[][] b = new boolean[4][4];

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
        Arrays.fill(b[i], false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make sense of iterating over multi dimensional arrays is like this.

```
boolean[][] seatArray = new boolean[4][4];

//Foreach row in seatArray
for(boolean[] arr : seatArray){
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++){
        arr[i] = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have already given a constant size of array, avoid using `.length` and use the constant instead.

```
for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++){ ... ... }}
```